# Limit width of a div slider

Tags: jquery

Haven't found a solution to this problem yet, have tried some things...
I have a slider script (find it here: http://jsfiddle.net/ND7cf/). Works nice, but I just cant get the slider to stop, when its at the end of the div box. You just can scroll forever.
Can you tell me how to fix this? Are there better solutions than this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick fix of your code:
http://jsfiddle.net/G6x6L/10/

But there is a lot of slider solutions for jQuery. 
I recommend you to use one:
http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/07/jquery-slider.html

Answer (score 1):

You can keep track of clicks with a variable : [another update](http://jsfiddle.net/ND7cf/11/).

In my solution, scrollTracker start at 1, click right increment, click left decrement.

```
$('#right-button').click(function() {
scrollTracker++;
...
$('#left-button').click(function() {
scrollTracker--;
```

When you begin scrollTracker is at 1 and you don't want to display left scroll :

```
scrollTracker > 1 ? leftButton.show() : leftButton.hide();
```

When you end scroll, your at max frame (totalFrames = $('.column').length in your case), and you hide right scroll:

```
scrollTracker < totalFrames ? rightButton.show() : rightButton.hide();
```

At the begining and each time you click, you update the scroll bar visibility.

Comment: ZenMaster's answer is nice, though I'd do it more dynamic. set a max of frames depending on how many column classes you have in there via:

var max = $('.column').length;

Comment: It works alright : http://jsfiddle.net/ND7cf/13/, just replace NUMBER_OF_FRAMES with $('.column').length; have a look

Comment: Thanks for your help! I used the solution of rogal111, but your solution is worth a thought, too! Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I updated the script http://jsfiddle.net/ND7cf/6/

Answer (score 0):

Replace below code with your js code and will work per you requirement
[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ND7cf/12/)

```
var margin_total= 0;

$('#right-button').click(function() {
if(margin_total > -900){  
    $('#box').animate({
    marginLeft: "-=450"
    }, "fast");
margin_total = margin_total - 450;
    console.log(margin_total);}
});

$('#left-button').click(function() {
if(margin_total < 0 ){
    $('#box').animate({
    marginLeft: "+=450"
    }, "fast");
margin_total = margin_total + 450; 
    console.log(margin_total);}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I added 3 parameters: curren-current page; leftMax-max value when you scroll to left; rightMax - max value when you scroll to right:
Here it is the working example:

```
var leftMax=0;
var rightMax=-2*450;
var currrent=0;
$('#right-button').click(function() {
    currrent=currrent-450;
    if(currrent<rightMax) currrent=rightMax;
    $('#box').animate({
    marginLeft: currrent
    }, "fast");
});
$('#left-button').click(function() {
    currrent=currrent+450;
    if(currrent>leftMax) currrent=leftMax;
    $('#box').animate({       
     marginLeft: currrent
    }, "fast");
});
```